# How to pass an array in Django to a template and use it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to pass an Array to a template and afterwards use it via JavaScript.

In my *views.py* I have:

```
arry1 = ['Str',500,20]
return render_to_response('test.html', {'array1': arry1})
```

And in my template:

```
var array1 = {{ array1 }};
```

but when I visit the website it outputs:

```
var array1 = [&#39;Str&#39;,500,20];
```

What do I have to change?

Comment: Please, be more specific.  How does this "obviously" break your code?  The JavaScript looks valid to me.

Comment: When I first posted the question stackoverflow reformatted & # 3 9 ; without the spaces to ' .
I think it has to be ' to work as intended in the JavaScript (or at least I assume it to work that way. But somehow there appears & # 3 9 ; (again without the spaces)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try using `{{ array1|safe }}` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: particularly helpful to me (and others?) moving from App Engine Django ver 0.96 to ver 1.2: in ver 1.2 you HAVE to use the safe filter whereas is 0.96 it used to just work...

Comment: What happens if one of elements in `array1` is datetime object. JavaScript doesn't recognize datetime. For example if `array1 = ['str', 500, 20, datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 23, 0, 0)]`

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned, you could use the `|safe` filter so Django doesn't sanitize the array and leaves it as is.

Another option, and probably the better one for the long term is to use the `simplejson` module (it's included with django) to format your Python list into a JSON object in which you can spit back to the Javascript. You can loop through the JSON object just like you would any array really.

```py
from django.utils import simplejson
list = [1,2,3,'String1']
json_list = simplejson.dumps(list)
render_to_response(template_name, {'json_list': json_list})
```

And in your Javascript, just `{{ json_list }}`

Comment: json_list becomes  
[1, 2, 3, & q u o t ;String1& q u o t ;]
(I added the spaces after &,q,u,o,t to prevent stackoverflow from reformating the output)
That also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe the best way is to use simplejson.dumps and afterwards the |safe filter?

Comment: You're right, you'd still need to use |safe in this case. Normally when I do JSON with Django I fetch it using an AJAX method (like $.getJSON from jQuery) so I never deal with having to use |safe.

Comment: simplejson.dumps removed since django 1.5 use json.dumps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048943/cannot-import-name-simplejson-after-installing-simplejson

Answer (score 7):

**In Django:**

```
from django.utils import simplejson
json_list = simplejson.dumps(YOUR_LIST)
```

AND PASS "json_list" IN CONTEXT

**IN JS:**

```
var YOUR_JS_LIST = {{YOUR_LIST|safe}};
```

Comment: It seems `simplejson` is no longer available beyond Django 1.5. Use Python's  json instead (`import json`)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by django core serializers. All you need to do is to serialize your data in json and than pass it to template.

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", <list>)
return render(request, 'view.html', {'data':data})
```

In your template save this list into javascript variable.

```
var list = {{data|safe}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try replacing `var array1 = {{ array1 }};` with `var array1 = '{{ array1|safe }}';` . I dont know why but this worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was added to Django, a candate for the same result is [json-script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script):

> `{{ value|json_script:"hello-data" }}`
>
> If value is the dictionary {'hello': 'world'}, the output will be:
>
> `<script id="hello-data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world"}</script>`
>
> The resulting data can be accessed in JavaScript like this:
>
> `const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);`

ID, "hello-data" in the case above will be optional on Django versions after 4.0.