# Django template language - Python array with Javascript index

Tags: javascript, python, django

Well, maybe this is a silly question, but i couldn't find the answer so far. So, i am rendering a view in Django (i will do the code generic to make the problem easier), and the python side looks something like this:

```
...
marray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
...
return render(request, "template.html", {"marray": marray})
```

Now, in the template.html file, I want to access the array, but the index must be determined by a JavaScript variable:

```
var index = 2;
var mvar = {{ marray.index }};
console.log(mvar);
```

Output wanted:

```
3
```

Obviously, the previous code does not work, it's just to show what I want. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array in Django to a template and use it with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739942/how-to-pass-an-array-in-django-to-a-template-and-use-it-with-javascript)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate due to the access to the index of the array in a single line. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var index = 2;
var marray = {{ marray|safe }};
var mvar = marray[index];
// OR: var mvar = {{ marray|safe }}[index];
```

Note that here `index` will probably either be constant, or be determined by the context, so there might be better ways to do this.

Comment: Great! var mvar = {{ marray|safe }}[index]; is what i was wanted. I don't know how it did not occur to me.

Many thanks.