# Django Templating Language HTML Filter

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to pass some variables from my view to my javascript. I cannot seem to find any thing online about converting python lists and dicts to JS.

```
<script>
    var list = '{{area_dict}}'
    console.log(list)
</script>
```

the console returned:

```
{&#39;9&#39;: [[&#39;Walls2&#39;, &#39;20&#39;], [&#39;asd&#39;, &#39;21&#39;]], &#39;22&#39;: [[&#39;BD 1&#39;, &#39;6&#39;]]}
```

while i just need 
{'9': [['Walls2', '20'], ['asd', '21']], '22': [['BD 1', '6']]}

It seems to convert my python into HTML; I need it to be the same style as my original python. Are there any django filters for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter:

```
<script>
    var list = {{area_dict | safe}}
    console.log(list)
</script>
```

Or check the other answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739942/how-to-pass-an-array-in-django-to-a-template-and-use-it-with-javascript)