# read Object from Django in Javascript

Tags: html, jquery, django

I have the following situation and I don't have any solution

I have the following view.py

```
def getData(request, ft):
context = {'hello': 'World',
        'ABC': 123,
        456: 'abc'}

    dataJSON = dumps(context)
    return HttpResponse(request, 'lic_usage_overview.html', {"data": dataJSON})
```

Now I need to assign these values to a array Object in javascript/jQuery. I tried in this way (and another 100 ways) but is not working:

```
<script>
var data = JSON.parse({{data|escapejs}});
for(var x in data){
    console.log(x+' : '+data[x]);
}
</script>
```

The console give me this as result:

```
VM574 jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Have anybody any idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739974/10606400) answer ?

Comment: yes I checked this answer and a lot similar like this one but I still have the problem because {{data|escapejs}} or {{data|safe}} is identity as error

Comment: Why not use ajax simply ?

Comment: would you be so kind to let me a simple example for this

Comment: Hi , i have limited knowledge in django .. but with your current updated code code i can see you are returning json from backend ..`{"data": dataJSON}` so why not called that page using ajax and get the return data i.e :`{"data": dataJSON}` .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should be able to use list comprehension that way. Try defining this in the view and pass it as a parameter to the template.